# Facebook Open Graph API - Fetch offers from page

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am currently working on a javascript project that fetches various data from a customer's Facebook page, so that it can be displayed on the customer's website.

One requirement of this project is that it can also fetch an display all offers that are currently active on the customer's Facebook page.

I already dug through the Open Graph API documentation and Facebook is listing two different endpoints to access offers from a Facebook page.

I tried `/{PAGEID}/nativeoffers` but this just gives me a empty response.
I also tried `/{PAGEID}/offers_v3` but I just get the following error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#3) User must be on whitelist",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 3,
        "fbtrace_id": "BV8zwWvE7Gv"
    }
}
```

Because of that, I have two questions:

- If I just want to fetch the standard offers of a Facebook page, which API endpoint do I have to use? `/nativeoffers` or `/offers_v3` ?
- How to get whitelisted to use `/offers_v3`? In the Open Graph API docs the description is as follows:
  `Entity to describe an offer. One needs to be whitelisted to use this API. Please contact the support group and ask them to reach out to the team that is responsible for this API to request to be whitelisted.`
  What support group is meant here?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?